# IIS Rewrite Rule using Url Path segments

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I'm trying to write, hopefully, a single rewrite rule for a number of URLs that are being moved to a different structure. All of the URLs have a very similar structure so I'm thinking there must be a way to write a single rule for all of them.

Example:

```
http://example.com/some/deep/path/a/001/my-a-data
http://example.com/some/deep/path/a/002/my-a-data2
http://example.com/some/deep/path/b/001/my-b-data
http://example.com/some/deep/path/b/002/my-b-data2
http://example.com/some/deep/path/c/001/my-c-data
http://example.com/some/deep/path/c/002/my-c-data2
```

Need to redirect to (respectively):

```
http://example.com/a/my-a-data
http://example.com/a/my-a-data2
http://example.com/b/my-b-data
http://example.com/b/my-b-data2
http://example.com/c/my-c-data
http://example.com/c/my-c-data2
```

So what I'm trying to know is if there is a way to read the segments of the PATH in the URL so I can just reuse them to build the final URL because it is all there. It is just a simplification of the URL.

Perhaps to do something like

```
                  /{1}/{2}/{3}/{4}/{5}/{6}
http://example.com/some/deep/path/a/001/my-a-data  ->  http://example.com/{4}/{6}
```

Is that possible?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found how it works.

Each segment in the URL path can be identified with {R} parameters in the rewrite rules. To match my URL structure I created the following rule:

```
<rule name="Documents redirection" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^some/deep/path/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$" ignoreCase="true" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="/{R:1}/{R:3}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Each of the (.*) segments are what the IIS Rewrite module recognizes as {R} parameter, so for my need, I needed the first and third parameter to form a new URL. I can safely ignore the second parameter.

I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 2):

It is recommended to use([^/])+ instead of (.*) . 
If there are multiple slash in your URL, the capture group would be corrupted.

For example:

[image]

[image]

Best regards,

Sam

Comment: That's very interesting. During my tests, I did find some issues but when I found my solution it did work correctly. I'll run some tests with your suggestion. Thanks @samwu

Comment: Actually, upon further review, the URL you're trying to match is not the URL I'm looking to recognize, if you use my pattern with my target URLs, you will see the parameters do work.